# Common Controls interrupting WM_KEYDOWN notifications

Tags: c, winapi

I have a window that creates a lot of other common controls such as menus, toolbars with buttons and combo boxes, and a status bar. The problem is that the window never receives a WM_KEYDOWN message whenever I press Enter or Esc, but I need to handle these. Is there any common control that is known to interrupt these keys?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a few things.
1) If the window is already open, try Window1.Focus();  (MSDN tells you that to focus, a form has to be visible, enabled, and have a handler)
2) If it's not open, try Window1.Activate();

In addition, WM_KEYDOWN can be annoying, you may want to try using SendKeys.Send() or SendKeys.SendWait() to send keystrokes.

Comment: When did I say anything about sending keystrokes? The window is in focus; every other key except Enter and Esc are received by its WndProc.

Answer (score 0):

Windows always sends WM_KEY*** messages to the window that has focus. So, all controls that take focus "interrupt" keyboard messages.

The general way to handle this is implicit in the operation of the [IsDialogMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645498(VS.85).aspx) function.

Keyboard messages are posted to the applications message queue. It is expected that keyboard messages that apply to the application as a whole are processed in the applications message loop. These keystrokes are normally called 'accelerators' and there is an API to deal with them: [TranslateAccelerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646373(VS.85).aspx)

Create an accelerator table describing the keystrokes, modify the message loop to pass all messages to TranslateAccelerator first, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't receive Enter and Esc keydowns, then you're most likely using the dialog translation mechanism: Enter is to dismiss the dialog with OK, Esc to dismiss it with Cancel.

If you need those two keys, you have to intercept the WM_GETDLGCODE message and handle the DLGC_WANTMESSAGE flag.
See [kb83302](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q83302/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing a plugin for Outlook right now.  I have a WinForms control hosted inside and it never receives the backspace key because it looks like the WM_KEY*** is actually turned into a WM_COMMAND in order to implement keyboard accelerators, as is probably your case.  Have you tried SPY++?